# What's the best scroll up/down method based on a particular locator in Android emulator?

Tags: java, android, selenium, appium, emulation

I have tried all of the ones available on Internet but none is working.

Using Appium 1.15 and Java-Client 7.0.0.

Problem is that,
If,

```
driver.findElementByAndroidUIAutomator("new UiScrollable( new UiSelector().scrollable(true).instance(0)).scrollIntoView"+"(new UiSelector().text(\"" + text + "\").instance(0))");
```

is used, then it keeps scrolling till the end of the page and then fails. For me, "text" is not just a button or text box. It can be a simple non-functional text on the page below which a dropdown will be present.

In the other approach:

```
TouchAction action = new TouchAction((PerformsTouchActions) driver);
    WebElement phone = driver.findElement(start);
    WebElement contact = driver.findElement(end);
    action.press((PointOption) phone)
    .waitAction()
    .moveTo((PointOption) contact)
    .release()
    .perform();
```

It fails while finding the element itself. Meaning, it does not proceed from the line: driver.findElemet(start) because this element is located at the bottom of the screen where I exactly need to scroll to.

Please help!

Comment: Have you tried to use Appium inspector to determine a locator for the element you try to scroll to?

Comment: Hey Yevhen Danchenko, I got the locator through Appium inspector itself.

Comment: I just tried the following strategy on the Mobile Google Chrome Settings screen:
`uiAutomator = "new UiScrollable(resourceIdMatches(\".*recycler_view\")).scrollIntoView(textMatches(\"About Chrome\"))`

And this works for me. Appium scroll down the screen and find `About Chrome` menu

Comment: @ Yevhen Danchenko, I tried what you tired too but whats "recycler_view" in your case? In my case, resource id is "android:id/title". If you want me to go with this resourceID approach all the time, then for some pages, I don't have this resourceID at all. Meaning, it will be empty. How in that case?

Comment: `.*recycler_view` - is a resource ID of the container which encloses menu items. So, you tell the driver to scroll within this container until the view with the text `About Chrome` became visible.

Comment: Thanks. But my case is completely different. Whether I try finding an element by resource-id or any other strategy, the element is found but won't scroll till there. It will not even throw an error saying element is not visible although I have tried with .isDisplayed(), isSelected() and stuff. When I slowly debug, element is there in the DOM somewhere at the bottom of the screen but when I do scroll, it won't scroll till there and the code exits saying it has scrolled down. In short, .isDisplayed and stuff is returning wrong checks.

Answer (score 0):

If the elements locators are correct and you confirm it, Try to use `driver.flick()` command. It do the same without wait. "Wait time" (that you define it with "Duration" arguman in any scroll class functions) has many prbolem with different device screen size.

For example: You have 3 element is a page: A , B , C
you try to scroll from A to B in a 5" screen size. The same code maybe scroll from A to C in 7" screen size!
So driver.flick() solve this.

Comment: Hey @adrenalineWest, thanks for the answer but that's not my problem statement. Also, I did try driver.flick(); but is not recognized in my code.